# Not able to build xAuthTwitterEngine Demo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter

Im trying to get the xAuthTwitterEngine Demo to run on Iphone simulator 3.0.
I changed the Base SDK in Project settings to Iphone Device 3.0 and Iphone OS deployment Target to Iphone OS 3.0
But my build fails with 18 errors. I dont understand why.
It has something to do with libOAuth.a and OAtoken.
Can someone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the errors. Are you using Xcode 3.2.2 or 3.2.3? You should use the latter, since libraries compiled with the "modern ABI" will not link under 3.2.2. As far as I understand, that should only matter when compiling for the simulator, not for the device, so this might not be the problem.

Comment: that was it. 3.2.3 made it work.

Comment: You should add an answer that updating fixed it and mark this question as solved.